# Which of the following of subspaces of $\mathbb{R^2}$ are compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, compactness

Which of the following of subspaces of $\mathbb{R^2}$ are compact ?

(a)  $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : xy = 0$}.

(b) $\{( \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n} )\in \mathbb{ R}^2 : n = 1, 2, . . . \} ∪ \{(0, 0)\}$.

(c)  $\{(r_n \cos n\phi, r_n \sin n\phi) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2\}$, where $\phi \in [0, 2\pi)$ and $\lim r_n = +\infty.$

(d) $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^ 6 + y^ 6 = 1\}$

*my work:*

(a) is closed but I am not sure about bounded

(b)  is close the set of limit point $(0,0)$ in that set don't idea 
about bounded

(c) No idea

(d) this set is closed and bounded so compact

Comment: some motivation about the dowvotes here? it seems well posed and motivated

Comment: @gimusi..thank you ...same in mind i don't know why i getting downvote..any way than you for your support

Comment: it should be useful to know the motivation in order to undertand what could be improved, fro me the OP is ok

Comment: @ SureshPonnada please try to expand your views about (a),(b),(c). to eliminate possibilities. In (c) have you seen carefully what is given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) is closed but i am not sure about bounded

- xy=0 correspond to x and y axis

(b)  is close the set of limit point $(0,0)$ in that set don't about bounded

- it is bounded since $0<\frac1n\le1$

(c) No idea

- it seems unbonded

(d) this set is closed and bounded so compact

- yes I agree

Comment: @gimusi...thank you sir

Comment: @SureshPonnada You're welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

(a) is not bounded (it's the axes).

(b) It's bound; it's a convergent sequence together with its limit.

(c) It's not bounded; the norms go to $+\infty$.

(d) Right.

Comment: .thanks you sir again i most of questions are answered :-)

Comment: @SureshPonnada I'm glad I could help.